# How to listen to Message Queue from Oracle 8i using C#

Tags: c#, oracle8i, advanced-queuing

I was able to use message queue API using Oracle 11g in C# by installing the Oracle ODAP for message Queue. I have an upgrage project for an old system that is built on Oracle 8i. Basically I cannot change the existing system so I was thinking on adding a Message Queue event via a insert table trigger. But I am wondering if there is a way to listen to that message queue in C#.

The current oracle website does not provide an ODAC for oracle 8i. But I am wondering if they have support or a hack to do this?

The alternative to this is just to do Polling every 1 second to monitor the table. What do you think?

Note: I read that java can do this via JMS but the requirement is for use in C#.
[see here](http://gbowyer.freeshell.org/oracle-aq.html)